# Batch script Latin characters

Tags: batch-file, character-encoding

I am writing a batch script to go through some directories doing an specific task, something like the following:

```
set DBCreationScript=//Here I set the full path for the script
echo %DBCreationScript%
```

Problem is the path has got some latin characters (ç, ã, á) and when I run the script, the output shows strange characters, not the ones I typed in. The batch script is in ANSI encoding.

I already tried to set the script encoding to UTF-8, but apparently the batch interpreter can't handle the control characters that appear on the beggining of the file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the batch file in OEM encoding (a decent editor should allow this) or change the code page prior to running it with

```
chcp 1252
```

You can also save it as UTF-8 without signature (BOM) and use

```
chcp 65001
```

but down that path lies peril and dragons await to eat you (in short: It's usually painful and has a few weird side-effects).

Comment: As a side note: OEM couldn't handle 'ã', only the other two chars (at least on my editor, notepad++). Anyway, chcp did the trick.

Comment: Well, that depends on which OEM codepage you're using. 850 (which is the default on my machine) supports it. But yes, that's the usual problem with non-Unicode encodings and a major reason why they should die already.